# Pre-calculus Rug Area to room area problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

A rectangular rug is in the middle of a room and there is a uniform width of floor that shows around the rug. The dimensions of the rug are 16ft by 21ft. What would the dimensions of the room have to be to make the area of the rug equal to the area of the floor around the rug?

So i found that the area of the rug is 336ft. Do I square this value to find the area of the whole room, then subtract the area of the rug from that to find the area around the rug?

Please help asap. Thanks

Comment: You would double the area of the rug as the area of the room, then write a quadratic formula as dimensions added to the rug width and height and solve.

Comment: How would I come up with the quadratic formula using the dimensions? The area of the room comes out to be: 112896 ft. The new width is: 256ft and the new height is 441ft.

Comment: No, don't square the rug area, just double it.

Comment: So the total room area is: 672ft. That is from doubling the area. Im not sure how to find the new length and width because doubling each side makes for: 32ft*42ft = 1344ft. Now from here, I have no clue where to go. im so lost.

Answer (score 1):

Note you are asked for the dimensions of the room, not the area of the room. Draw a picture of the scenario. I cannot emphasize how important this is. Now assign the unknown additional room lengths to the variable $x$.

Here is one way: Put the rug in the center (does not really matter), and let $x$ be the additional floor lengths needed on all 4 sides of the rug. Now you have dimensions $16+2x$, and $21+2x$. Now take that corresponding area in terms of $x$, set it equal to two times 336, and solve for $x$. Doing it this way, your new room dimensions will be $16+2x$, by $21+2x$.
Don't respond until you have drawn a picture.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I have drawn a picture. So with the new values I get: 16+2x+21+2x=672. 4x+37=672. 4x=635. x=158.75.
So now do I just plug that in and get: 16+2(158.75) and 21+2(158.75) and that gives me the new dimensions?

Comment: Good on the picture, but you want to multiply for area my friend, as in $(16+2x)(21+2x)=672$. You are setting areas equal to areas.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. So I do the foiling and get: 4x^2 + 74x + 336 = 672. I hate to have you walk me through it step by step but I still dont know where to go from here. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Im not sure what to do with that equation..?

Comment: Ouch. You need to subtract 672 from both sides, to have zero on the right, and then be able to solve a quadratic equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Have you learned/been taught how to do this already?

Comment: Yea I tried that before but nothing seems to work out evenly. I come to get: 2(x^2 + 37x - 168) = 0 and there arent any perfect factors. The closest thing for factors are 42 & 4 and those wont foil)
If you use the quadratic formula to find the factors one is: -60.97 and the other is: -87.021

Comment: You should have $2(2x^2+37x-168)=0$, divide across by two, then solve $2x^2+37x-168=0$. You cannot factor this over integers. You need to use the quadratic formula, or complete the square. Have you learned/been taught the quadratic formula?

Comment: Yes I have learned this I just have a lot on my plate tonight on top of multiple other things and im trying to do them all. I used the quadratic formula and got 2 values: -23.98 and -50.02. Now I dont have a clue what to do with these as for where to apply them for the dimensions.

Comment: You applied the formula wrong. When you do it right, there will be two solutions, one positive, and one negative. Take the positive solution. If you plug it into a calculator it will be approximately $x \approx 3.77$. Read back through my post to see the new room dimensions. I am glad to talk to you, but we need to stop the responses here, as it is excessive according to site policies and I cannot bring you into chat. Just vote on the answer after you succeed to let me know you had success.

Comment: I gave you a vote for supporting the OPs efforts :-)